# "node --debug" and "node --debug-brk" are invalid

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, visual-studio-2017

I have updated the node (v8.1.2). When I want to debug my previous test project in nodejs using NTVS (in visual studio 2017) I've gotten the following error:

> StandardError: (node:5292) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead.

The problem is clear. The tool try to run the `node --debug` to start the project.

The question is, how can I change `node --debug` to `node --inspect` in Visual Studio 2017 to running the test?

Also, I should have mentioned that I can't solve the problem by adding `--inspect` into the Script Arguments.

Comment: Can't you have a npm script for that? My suggestion is for you to create a debug script in package.json

Comment: This is unlikely to happen in professional software, i.e. that from one version to another the software denies service by changing the command names.

Comment: So many other SO questions about this, all from different angles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623841/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49334812/ at the very least.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Chrome's DevTools to debug as below:

1. Start Node with `--inspect option ...`
   e.g. `$node --inspect app.js`.
   You should see a console printout something like

   > Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/2558baab-1141-4db3-8d10-771586f876a6
2. Open Chrome browser and browse to
   `chrome://inspect`.
   Click on "Open dedicated DevTools for Node" link.

Answer (score 2):

I did this:
1. `mv /usr/local/bin/node  /usr/local/bin/node_bin`
2. `echo > /usr/local/bin/node`
3. `editor /usr/local/bin/node`
 insert script:

```
#!/bin/bash
## the script converting parameters for nodejs new version
##
new_name="node_bin";
eval _options="(" $(echo -e $@) ")"
_node=$(whereis -b $new_name|awk '/^'$new_name':/{print $2}');                                                                              
eval _version="(" $(echo -e $($_node --version|sed 's/[^0-9]/ /g')) ")";                                                                    
# local values                                                                                                                              
old_options=( "--debug" "--debug-brk" );                                                                                                    
new_options=( "--inspect" "--inspect-brk" );                                                                                                
_opt=();                                                                                                                                    

function filtr() {                                                                                                                          
    _opt=${_options[@]};                                                                                                                    
    for ((get_i=0; get_i != ${#old_options[@]}; get_i++))                                                                                   
        do                                                                                                                                  
        if [ ${new_options[$get_i]} = "" ];
            then
                _opt=${_opt[@]};
            else
                _opt=$( echo -e ${_opt[@]}|sed 's/'${old_options[$get_i]}'/'${new_options[$get_i]}'/g');
        fi
    done

}

function convert() {

if [ $(echo -e ${#_options[@]}) = 0 ];
    then 
        $_node;
    else
     filtr;

        $_node $(echo -e ${_opt[@]})
fi
exit 0;
}

if (( ${_version[0]} >= 7 ));
 then
   convert;
fi
exit 0;
```

4. `chmod ugo+x /usr/local/bin/node`
   I will not say that the decision is elegant, but it helped me.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still having this issue, in your `wdio.conf.js` replace
`debug: true, execArgv: ['--debug=127.0.0.1:5859']` with 
`inspect: true, execArgv: ['--inspect=127.0.0.1:5859']`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, and it was fixed by updating to VS2017 version 15.2.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the IDE vsc  to the newest version(v1.13)，my node version is v8.0.0 ;it can solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should downgrade your nodejs to 7.0.0 or less. 
Use NVM on windows, see this [post](https://medium.com/appseed-io/how-to-run-multiple-versions-of-node-js-with-nvm-for-windows-ffbe5c7a2b47).

you can have several node´s version, on your computer.

luck!

Comment: I need the nodejs v8! So, this update is done consciously.

Comment: I do not know, I think this update is an incomplete version. Well i have used the v7, and it didn't show errors