# verb(node:14096) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid

Tags: node.js, debugging

I have installed nodeJs and setup on my machine with VS 2015. When I try to run the sample hello world application, its throwing the below error:

```html
verb(node:14096) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: 
`node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. 
Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead.
Press any key to continue...
```

Please help me to resolve this and running the application.

Venkatesh.

Comment: what version of nodejs you have installed?

Comment: There are already a lot of similar questions asked, please refer them once. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/27704   
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752665/node-debug-and-node-debug-brk-are-invalid  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21883

Comment: I see that we need to add the below to resolve this issue

"(In short: add a "protocol": "inspector" or "protocol": "auto" to your launch configuration)."

Can some one please help me to find this launch configuration file ? Where is this file located ?

Comment: I am using v8.5.0 version.