# (node:11684) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --inspect --debug-brk` is deprecated. Please use `node --inspect-brk` instead

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I am getting this error running Nodejs from Visual Studio 2017 since i upgrade NodeJs.

Also breakpoints are not working. 
Any way to fix this?

Note: 
VS version is 15.5.6
NodeJS version 8.9.4

Comment: I tested it with exactly same version as yours, VS2017 15.5.6  and NodeJS 8.9.4, but it works fine in my machine, what I created was Blank Node.js Web application, code is simple, only output "hello world". If you don't mind, please share the project type with sample code that I could try to reproduce it in my side.

Comment: I downgrade the nodeJs to version 7.10.1 and now it works.
Still, if you want to take a look, i uploaded to https://github.com/byte-artisan/nodeJsTest/tree/master/SandboxJS.

Comment: @ByteArtisan, Do you mean that you have resolved this issue? If so, would you mind sharing your solution as the answer? So it could help other community members. Have a nice day:)

Comment: I downgrade as o posted, what i don't consider a solution but an workaround. Probably, we will have to wait for an update of Visual Studio.

Comment: @ByteArtisan, Could you share a simple sample using one drive? I will download and debug it using different VS2017 Environments.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, and following has worked for me.

**1st solution**

change in your launch.json from

```
< "protocol": "legacy",
> "protocol": "auto",
```

This should work.

**2nd solution**

In package.json:

```
scripts: {
  "debug": "DEBUG=pd* nodemon --inspect-brk --harmony --nolazy server.js"
}
```

Then default debug launch configuration for node from latest VS Code:

```
{  
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach",
    "port": 9229
}
```

Both have worked for me.

Comment: Problem is that i am using VS2017. Those configurations don't seam to work on VS 2017.